# Blazor button onclick event is never called

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, blazor

I have a new Blazor project, I have added 2 buttons :

1 - a normal button
2 - a MatBlazor button

I try to call a simple method on the click event, but none work !

```
        <MatButton OnClick="@(() => Logout())" Icon="exit_to_app" Label="Log out" />
        <MatButton OnClick="@OnClickHandler" Icon="exit_to_app" Label="Log out 2" />
        <button @onclick="@OnClickHandler">Log out 3</button>

@code {

    public void OnClickHandler(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/Account/Logout");
    }

    //public void Logout(/*MouseEventArgs e*/)
    public async Task Logout()
    {
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/Account/Logout");
    }

}
```

I have tried a lot of combinations, but now way, none of the methods is called!

Comment: Are you sure that the methods do not work? Put a break point already?

Comment: Why the MouseEventArgs in a buttonclick?  But basically they should all work, at least the bottom one. I don't know the MatButton.

Comment: I put my sample below, I tested 4 cases and all of them work

Comment: Your public async Task Logout() does not have a await, it cannot be compiled

Comment: @HieuLe - it will compile (and function) albeit with a warning.

Comment: @HenkHolterman show on my side error CS0161: 'Counter.OnClickHandler(MouseEventArgs)': not all code paths return a value

Comment: You don't have `async` there.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I see, thank guy

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204671/discussion-between-hieu-le-and-henk-holterman).

Comment: No, I don't like chat. And we are done here, are we not?

Answer (score 1):

Everything works well on my side. I create a new .Net Core 3.1 LTS project

```
<p>Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="OnClickHandler">Click me</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="()=> IncrementCount()">Click me 2</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="@OnClickHandler">Click me 3</button>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="@(() => IncrementCount())">Click me 4</button>

@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;

    public void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
    }

    public Task OnClickHandler(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        currentCount++;

         return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have put this code in my project, but none work !! It should be something with my 'setup' ? There is something that break this behavior, right ?

Comment: Why don't you create a completely new blazor project? There is a counter button in that project. Then you can try testing and comparing

Answer (score 1):

The standard version is

```
  <button @onclick="Logout">Log out 3</button>`
```

...

```
public async Task Logout()
{
    NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/Account/Logout");
}
```

When this doesn't work there might be something wrong with `NavigateTo()`

Start with putting a breakpoint in Logout() to verify it is called.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add this line and it worked:

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
```

Answer (score 0):

I used `MatButton onClick` attribute by providing `delegate`

```
<MatButton TrailingIcon="favorite" @onclick="@(async () => await AddItemtoShoppingCart(@item))" Label="add"></MatButton>
```

Below is my method.

```
@code {
public async Task AddItemtoShoppingCart(FoodItem selectedItem)
    {
        selectedItem.AddedToCart = true;
    }
}
```